# Delay and no delay on the same element?

Tags: html, css

HTML CODE

```
<select name="server" id="server" class="nofocus">
   <option value="X">X</option>
     <option value="XX">XXE</option>
     <option value="XXX">XXX</option>
     </select>
```

CSS CODE

```
#server { 
border: solid 1px #eeeeee;
  padding: .2em .25em .15em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
    }

#server:focus { background: rgba(0, 34, 255, 0.2);
                transition-delay:0.5s;
 }

.nofocus:focus { color:#FFF00; }
```

So what I'm trying to do is have some styling "start" with a delay and some styling start as soon as the element is focused.
It only shows me the #server and #server:focus code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify the property you want the transition to apply, so the other properties (*like the `color`*) are not affected.

```
#server:focus { 
    background: rgba(0, 34, 255, 0.2);
    transition:background;
    transition-delay:0.5s;
}
```

Additionally the color you specify (*`#FFF00`*) is incorrect (*only has 5 hex digits instead of 3 or 6*)

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/yLSXc/1/

Comment: It's mistyped, should have been #FF0000.

Answer (score 1):

You can use transition shorthand to specify that styles be transitioned in different ways.

```
#server {
transition: height 1s 1s, opacity 1s;
}
```

When two values are given, the first value is the delay, the second is the duration

More info here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition